# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

Tags: next.js, babeljs, glsl

I have a Next.js website and I'm trying to import `glsl` via `import glsl from "babel-plugin-glsl/macro"`, but I'm encountering the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')`.

I got this error while trying to work around another error (related to accessing the `fs` module by the said package).

According to the plugin's [usage instructions](https://github.com/onnovisser/babel-plugin-glsl#usage), you can include it in your `.babelrc` file and that's it. When doing that, I got the error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

I solved the error above by trying an alternative usage method indicated by the plugin's creator: adding the `babel-plugin-macros` package. Now after adding this package and including in the `.babelrc` file, I get the error  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')` — which I'm unable to debug since it's not coming from any file I author.

I even tried importing it via `getServerSideProps` but I got the same error.

=============================================================================

```js
// test.js
import glsl from "babel-plugin-glsl/macro"

const TestPage = () => {
  console.log(glsl)

  return <div>Test Page</div>
}

export default TestPage

// export async function getServerSideProps() {
//   const glsl = require("babel-plugin-glsl/macro")

//   return {
//     props: {
//       glsl
//     }
//   }
// }
```

```json
// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["glsl", "macros"],
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.5.3",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.0.12",
    "baffle": "^0.3.6",
    "gsap": "^3.9.1",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-tabs": "^3.2.2",
    "three": "^0.139.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "babel-plugin-glsl": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "glslify": "^7.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.3"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: that sounds like its attempting to load some node modules in the browser